# pandas not dropping or filling missing value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill the missing value but pandas `.fillna` not filling that value. I tried to drop these but the drop method too not working, need support.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 76199 entries, 0 to 76198
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Age(Yrs.)       74982 non-null  float64
 1   Weight(Kg)      74982 non-null  float64
 2   Height (ft.)    74982 non-null  float64
 3   Diseases        74982 non-null  object 
 4   Breakfast       74982 non-null  object 
 5   Lunch           74982 non-null  object 
 6   Dinner          74982 non-null  object 
 7   Diseases_code   76199 non-null  int64  
 8   Breakfast_code  76199 non-null  int64  
 9   Lunch_code      76199 non-null  int64  
 10  Dinner_code     76199 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(3), int64(4), object(4)
memory usage: 6.4+ MB
```

**df.fillna(method ='pad')**
I use this but not getting desired output. It is still showing values that are missing.

Comment: The `DataFrame.fillna` method does not work inplace, so you either need to re-assign the output (`df = df.fillna(...)`) or you need to instruct the operation to be performed inplace (`df.fillna(..., inplace=True)`).

Comment: Thank you v much, it works for me